# Table row Animation using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I try to add a JQuery animation in each row when it is inserted into a `div`. My code is showed below, it is perfectly working but without animation:

```
var table=$("<table width='100%' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='10' font-size='16px'id='#my_table'>");
    $.each(json.records, function(idx, item) {              
        table.append(
            $('<tr class="tabrowstyle">').append(
                $('<td width=10%>').text(item.A),
                $('<td width=20%>').text(item.B),
                $('<td width=20%>').text(item.C),
                $('<td width=20%>').text(item.D),
                $('<td width=10%>').text(item.E),
                $('<td width=20%>').text(item.F)                                   
            ).append('</tr>'));
        });

    $(this).addClass('tabrowstyle');
    table.append("</table>").appendTo("#div_content");
```

Comment: Append will not work like a string concatenation!

Comment: Append will add the target element as a last child to the source.